# Unable to create image in magento api if product SKU contains slash(/)

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm trying to create an image via magento image api by following the same code in this [magento doc](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_attribute_media.).

And its working fine except the SKU contains slash(/) character.

SKU: `SPA-1XCHOC12/DS0`

Here is the Error shows in `httpd/error_log`:

```
[Fri Feb 21 07:35:33 2014] [error] [client 8.35.201.40] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [104] Cannot create image. in /var/www/html/product_api/image.php:22\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/product_api/image.php(22): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/product_api/image.php(22): SoapClient->call('67da4ad39466d6e...', 'product_media.c...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/product_api/image.php on line 22
```

To identify the exact issue, i have added this code

`$this->_fault('not_created', $e->getMessage());` in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Media/Api.php`

And this is the error:

```
[Fri Feb 21 07:41:56 2014] [error] [client 8.35.201.42] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [104] Folder 'SPA-1XCHOC12' isn't writeable in /var/www/html/product_api/image.php:22\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/product_api/image.php(22): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)\n#1 /var/www/html/product_api/image.php(22): SoapClient->call('7f82eac2c509869...', 'product_media.c...', Array)\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/product_api/image.php on line 22
```

And `media/catalog/product` folder permission is `777`. Still showing the same error.

**Here is my Code:**

Post Values are `sku = 'SPA-1XCHOC12/DS0'` and `image_url='http://example.com/11233.jpg'`

```
$sessionId = $proxy->login($api_user, $api_pwd);  

$newImage = array(
     'file' => array(
        'name' => $_POST['sku'],
        'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($_POST['img_url'])),
        'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
     ),
     'position' => 0,
     'types'    => array('small_image', 'image', 'thumbnail'),
     'exclude'  => 0
);

$imageFilename = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.create', array($_POST['sku'], $newImage));
```

Comment: just a thought, replace `/` with `_`, or use product ID

Comment: @waldek_c But it will make some difficulty for Sales people who have access to magento admin. Thats why. :(

Comment: Why difficulty? My thought was, that in your code, before saving image, filter product SKU and replace "strange chars" like `/` nothing will change for Admin users

Comment: waldek_c is right. Refer http://www.andrewbrettwatson.com/index.php/help/187-sku-best-practices-for-online-shopping-sites

Comment: You can not have anything inputted as SKU. There should be some best prectices  to allow SKU. You can read more in the previous link

Comment: @DushyantJoshi Understood. I tried to add the same SKU that are provided by Cisco.

Comment: Difficulty with the file system which uses `/` for a delimiter or difficulty with your sales people. You'll need to inconvenience the sales people... They don't need to see the image file name anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Since your image is being generated by the sku, which you are sending to the routine manually, then why not clean it up there.  It won't affect anything else.

Post Values are sku = 'SPA-1XCHOC12/DS0' and image_url='http://example.com/11233.jpg'

```
$sessionId = $proxy->login($api_user, $api_pwd);  

// Replace slashes like waldek_c suggested
$sku_filename = str_replace("/","_",$_POST['sku']).".jpg";

$newImage = array(
 'file' => array(
    'name' => $sku_filename,     // Put filtered $sku_filename var here from above
    'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($_POST['img_url'])),
    'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
),
 'position' => 0,
 'types'    => array('small_image', 'image', 'thumbnail'),
 'exclude'  => 0
);

$imageFilename = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.create', array($_POST['sku'], $newImage));
```

The image filename will be `SPA-1XCHOC12_DS0.jpg` instead of `SPA-1XCHOC12/DS0`.